# Can't login into phpMyAdmin with my correct login data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2, php-7

First time I see this problem.

On Debian Jessie 8 I install php7, apache2, mysql client and phpmyadmin.

I set all paswords and usernames, all works well but when I try to access in phpmyadmin, when enter username & password, page refresh without error and nothing happen, just stay on login page. If I enter wrong data I see error message and that's ok but again when insert correct login details - nothing happen.

I not see any error messages in logs.

Only what I do in `php.ini` is that I uncomment `session.save_path` and point to `/tmp` folder.

What to do?